# Is Amazon EC2 (C4 instances) a shared memory (single address space) architecture?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm planning to rent an Amazon EC2 c4 instance for HPC, but I can't understand its architecture. Are all vCPU sharing the same address space? 4.8xlarge 36 vCPU too? Can I use shared memory communication between threads without data transmission overhead (OpenMP) or is better to go straight a message passing communication (OpenMPI)?

Answer (score 1):

They do share the same address space, a large instance is a single virtual machine, not a cluster, so you can just use OpenMP.